# Ubuntu SSH GUI issue

Tags: 16.04, networking, virtualbox, ssh, oracle

I am running ubuntu server in a virtualbox. The ubuntu server has a LXD container inside which i wish to install a software(specifically, Oracle DB).

I connect to my virtual ubuntu server using SSH -X username@ip from my local machine and whenever i open any GUI application it port forwards my request to the local machine and displays it as expected.

Now i need the same kind of port forwarding when i run my Oracle installer inside the LXD but I instead get

```
Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. 
Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.
```

Currently my steps are:

1) From my local machine,i do SSH -X username@ip after starting my virtual machine in virtualbox.

2) I then do

```
sudo lxc exec container -- sudo --login --user ubuntu
```

3) Here, i have a copy of my installer. I tried running it and got the error

```
Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. 
Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.
```

So, Port forwarding works fine from inside just the virtualbox but not from inside the LXD container of the virtualbox. Kindly help.

I checked my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and yes, the x11forwarding is set to yes. I also changed my DISPLAY variable inside lxd to `localhost:10.0` and `:0` but had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to set DISPLAY manually:

1. On the client check for `ForwardX11` yes in `~/.ssh/config` or use `ssh -x`.
2. On the server `X11Forwarding yes` must specified in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
3. The xauth program must be installed on the server side.

References:
[How to forward X over SSH to run graphics applications remotely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely)

Comment: Yes, i verified all the above parameters and it still shows `cannot open display`

Comment: Have you configured the netowork inside the container?

Comment: Yes, i have. Infact i have postgresql installed in my LXD and i am able to communicate with it from outside without any issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I found out the mistake from the network part you suggested. My port 22 was not open to traffic. I did that with `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`